# Order search results by multiple post_types

Tags: wp-query

Im constructing my custom wp_query with something like this:

```
if (is_search()) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'any',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post__not_in'  =>  EXCLUDE_IDS_FROM_SEARCH,
            's'             =>  get_search_query(),
            'orderby'       => 'post_type',
            'order'         => 'DESC'
        );
    }

$qry = new WP_Query( $args );
```

My current search result is ordered by post_types like this:

- post
- page
- custom_post_type_1
- custom_post_type_2

I'm trying to have pages ordered last. Is there a way to achieve this, without a custom mysql query?

Comment: Not without SQL, no. Any specific reason you want to avoid SQL? You can add SQL a with a filter to a query without writing a whole query.

Comment: @JacobPeattie probably the only reason as of know is that I fear that i'll open a backdoor, due to my lack of knowledge when it comes to mysql. Thats why I prefer any built-in options, because wordpress takes care of the above. I may try a few times later, maybe I can get something to work, in order to post here and get feedback about it.